# Benchmarking on Github Codespace

Tags: javascript, frameworks, benchmarking, github-codespaces, bun

I'm doing a benchmark for HTTP frameworks on Github Codespace. I don't have that much experience with benchmarking so I don't know if Github Codespace is actually stable or not for benchmarking. I did a few tests and the result is not that consistent but I don't know if i did anything wrong.

You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/bunsvr/benchmark).
What I'm doing now is to spawn a different process to run the server and then spawn another process for benchmarking with Bombardier.

I use the BunJS runtime, a quite new one so you may be not familiar with the libs.

Should I keep this solution or build Docker images of each of the framework? Or should I benchmark on Github Codespace?